# Geometrical meaning of A4 conjugacy classes of elements of order 3

Tags: group-theory, geometry, permutations, permutation-cycles

I know that elements of order 3 in A4 group split into two separate conjugacy classes, due to lack of odd elements to form a unique class like happens in the full S4.

Since A4 is the rotation symmetry group of the Tetrahedron, I was wondering if these two split conjugacy classes have a direct geometrical meaning. While I can see a direct meaning of transpositions, clearly distinguishing them from 3-cycles, I cannot see any apparent related split of them from a geometrical perspective.

Nevertheless, my feeling is this binding makes sense, hiding somewhere from my view.

Would you point me to the right direction, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Non-identity solutions to $x^3=e$ come in pairs. (This is true in any group.)

Comment: Thank @Shaun, but this is yet another algebraic explanation of that, which makes a lot sense to me, of course. However, my doubt is more strictly related to explain that inside the context of A4 as Tetrahedron rotation symmetry group. I mean: in D12 (symmetry of hexagon) it's clear the transpositions form different classes, depending if the reflection axis is taken from vertex to vertex or from midpoint to midpoint (and this happens only on even Dihedral groups). I'm trying to find a similar geometrical on A4 as Tetrahedron rotation group, since in this case all 3-cycles seem undistinguishable

Answer (score 3):

For me, it is helpful to see the conjugacy classes of $A_4$ listed out:

[image]

Now, let there be a tetrahedron sitting on a desk. Label the three vertices on the desk $1,2,3$, going clockwise, and label the vertex at the top as $4$. Now, if you rotate the tetrahedron $120^\circ$ degrees clockwise, that would be like the cycle $(123)$. Rotate it counterclockwise, however, and that would be like the cycle $(132)$.

Now, turn the tetrahedron so that the vertex $1$ is now on top. You will now notice that, in clockwise order, the vertices on the desk are $2,4,3$. Thus, rotate the tetrahedron $120^\circ$ degrees clockwise, and that would be like the cycle $(243)$. Rotate it counterclockwise, and that would be like the cycle $(234)$.

Again, turn the tetrahedron so that the vertex $2$ is now on top. In  clockwise order, the vertices on the desk are now $1,3,4$. Thus, rotate the tetrahedron $120^\circ$ degrees clockwise, and that would be like the cycle $(134)$. Rotate it counterclockwise, and that would be like the cycle $(143)$.

Hopefully, you can guess what will happen if you turn the tetrahedron so that the vertex $3$ is on top. Anyway, I hope you can now see how the conjugacy class with $(123)$ corresponds to clockwise rotations when looking from above while the conjugacy class with $(132)$ corresponds to counter-clockwise rotations when looking from above.

Comment: thanks @Noble Mushtak, this was exactly the meaning I was looking for. Cool.

Comment: However, of course (132) could be seen still as CW rotations. I'm still wondering why this CW/CCW trick does not apply to rotations in dihedral groups. I mean, taking D12 (symmetry of the Tetrahedron), the rotations a split in 3 conjugacy classes (naming the Hexagon vertices as the usual 1---6): {(135)(246)}, {(123456)(165432)} and {(14)(25)(36)} which belongs to the Z(D12) as forms a class by itself. In this case, the CW and CCW rotations belong to the same pertaining classes. Is this because rotations commute in plain 2D space, while rotations in 3D are not? Thanks

Comment: @riccardoventrella I think the reason the CW/CCW trick doesn't work for conjugacy classes of $D_{12}$ is because $D_{12}$ has a reflection permutation which allows you to turn clockwise into counterclockwise roations. Meanwhile, in the above scenario, there's no way to reflect the whole tetrahedron over some plane. Yes, you can rotate the tetrahedron so that, from some perspective, $(132)$ looks clockwise and $(123)$ looks counterclockwise. However, by such rotation, you are changing the location of vertex $4$, which changes things.

Comment: sorry, I put some TYPOs above, I really mean: {(135)(246), (153)(264)}, {(123456), (165432)}, while the latter {(14)(25)(36)} was correct.

Comment: This is why I looked at the problem by fixing the triangle base on a desk: That way, you can clearly see that, from the perspepctive of vertex 4, the only way you can change the vertices $1,2,3$ is by rotating the triangle, and there is no way to reflect these vertices without rotating the whole tetrahedron upside down.

Comment: thanks @Noble Mushtak, you are right the scenario is completely different and this relates to my hint about 2D Vs 3D as well. However, when I was citing (132) permutation above, I really meant you can see it as a plain CW rotations of 2/3PI degrees, so you can build up all your reasoning above with just plain CW rotations, so in this case I'm still puzzling a bit.

Comment: However in full CW reasoning, we can still apply yours replacing CW by PI/3 rotations and CCW by 2/3PI ones, having all them as plain CW. So yes, we have still a split where now conjugacy classes mean "PI/3 CW rotations" Vs "2/3PI CW rotations". It's a mere renaming of that.

Comment: @riccardoventrella Yes, you can also label the conjugacy classes as both clockwise rotations, but with different angles. In any case, there is still a clear distinction between the different geometric rotations.